# window.history.pushstate have probelm when ajax and post back request occur simultaneously

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am facing on a problem in window.history.pushstate. i am using ajax for pagination, then after i click on any other post back link after then i click on back button, browser load only ajax content instead of whole page

Javascript code is below

```
$("#page-summary").on("click", ".ajax-paginator a, table > thead > tr > th > a", function()
{
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    $("#page-summary").load(href, function()
    {
         App.initAjax();
         window.history.pushState({url : href}, document.title, href);
    });

    return false;
});

window.addEventListener('popstate', function(e) 
{
     if (e.state) 
     {
         $("#page-summary").load(e.state.url, function()
         {
              App.initAjax();
         });
     }
});
```

Normal Page

[image]

when i click on post back link then click on browser back button
it show me below
[image]